# 400 bad request,Is there any problem with the code in controller?

Tags: ajax, spring-mvc

I'm trying to send data to controller by ajax,but met with problem Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 (Bad Request).I don't know which part of the problem

JS:

```
var info ={
        "questions":{"q1":trim(q1), "q2":trim(q2),"q3":trim(q3),"q4":trim(q4),"q5":trim(q5),"q6":trim(q6),"q7":trim(q7),"q8":trim(q8)},
        "answers":{"datetimepicker":datetimepicker,"sexual":sexual,"nation":nation, "province":province,"city":city, "sheng":sheng,"shi":shi,"xian":xian, "height":height,"weight":weight}
    };
    var info_str = JSON.stringify(info);
$.ajax({
    type:'GET',
    data:info_str,
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    url :'/yiban',
    success :function(data) {
        alert(data);
    },
    error :function(e) {
        alert("error");
    }
});
```

Java:

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/yiban", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public void yiban(HttpServletRequest request)
    {
        String jsonStr = request.getParameter("info_str");
        JSONObject questions = JSONObject.fromObject(jsonStr).getJSONObject("questions");
        JSONObject answers = JSONObject.fromObject(jsonStr).getJSONObject("answers");
        String q1 = questions.getString("q1");
        String ans = answers.getString("nation");
        System.out.println(q1);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/yiban", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public void yiban(HttpServletRequest request) throws IOException {
        //GET method parameter is passed with url  ,  json  data can't go with url. json or xml is passed  in request boy
//        String jsonStr = request.getParameter("info_str"); 
        ServletInputStream inputStream = request.getInputStream();
        String  jsonStr=StreamUtils.copyToString(inputStream, Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
        JSONObject questions = JSONObject.fromObject(jsonStr).getJSONObject("questions");
        JSONObject answers = JSONObject.fromObject(jsonStr).getJSONObject("answers");
        String q1 = questions.getString("q1");
        String ans = answers.getString("nation");
        System.out.println(q1);
    }
```

Above is my code which works in my project . 
Firstly  ,use POST to send json or xml! 
and use request.getInputStream to receive json data!
Secondly you RequestMappingMethod returns nothing, your front web receive nothing !
What view you want to return to Front?